# Java import problems

Tags: java, import

The import statement in Java seems to be acting bizarre, I've checked with Java The Complete Reference and I can't see why something isn't working.

I have two files one in first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java and another in first/mysql/test/Main.java and an import statement in the latter for first.mysql.MySQLAccess isn't working.

```
package first.mysql.test;

import first.mysql.MySQLAccess;
```

MySQLAccess.java starts with

```
package first.mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

public class MySQLAccess {
```

I can't work out why this won't work, it should work perfectly unless I've missed something. I've compiled MySQLAccess.java and it produced MySQLAccess.class

```
Main.java:1: error: package first.mysql does not exist
import first.mysql.MySQLAccess;
                   ^
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    MySQLAccess dao = new MySQLAccess();
    ^
symbol:   class MySQLAccess
location: class Main
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    MySQLAccess dao = new MySQLAccess();
                          ^
symbol:   class MySQLAccess
location: class Main
3 errors
```

I've compiled with:

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ javac first/mysql/test/Main.java
```

Source code:
first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java: http://pastebin.com/7WkewTEf
first/mysql/test/Main.java: http://pastebin.com/aSsn34fX

I have found a clue to the weird behaviour, java does not seem like like MySQLAccess.class...

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ java first/mysql/MySQLAccess.class
Error: Could not find or load main class first.mysql.MySQLAccess.class
```

Comment: You haven't said how you're compiling or what the error is, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: Where have you compiled it to? Can the compiler for the second file find it, i.e. do you need to specify a classpath for the compiler?

Comment: I've ran the compiler from a folder called mysqlexample, to Java code in a subdirectory first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java and first/mysql/test/Main.java the class files are with the source files.

Comment: Can you try import first.mysql.* to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: What's your project structure ? hope you have src and test directories  and in these two source files are in same project ? as others said its difficult to help without more details.

Comment: It still gave me errors for line 7 as if the class MySQLAccess wasn't there when I imported first.mysql.*

Comment: I've added links to the source code on pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason - first.mysql.MySQLAccess.java wasn't compiled successfully to begin with, or it was compiled directly under /mysql - negating the package structure. The source may be there, but as far as first.mysql.test.Main.java is concerned, it will only look for first.mysql.MySQLAccess.class.

First, make sure you have this structure:

```
mysqlexample 
  |--first
       |--mysql
          |--test
             |-- Main.java
       MySQLAccess.java
```

Then issue these commands:

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ javac first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java

john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ javac first/mysql/test/Main.java
```

Comment: I got "first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java uses or overrides a deprecated API" but it seems to have produced a .class file for MySQLAccess.java. It uses java.sql.Date which is depreciated, do I need to move to Calendar? I just wanted to get the example running.

Comment: It's ok. That's not a problem. Can you share the command you used when compiling MySQLAccess?

Comment: javac first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java

Comment: change import first.mysql.*; to import first.mysql.MySQLAccess;

Comment: That does not work either, it still gave me errors for line 7 as if the class MySQLAccess wasn't there.

Comment: Make a very simple MySQLAccess and compile it: http://pastebin.com/hZQkdYCk. The idea is to isolate whether one of the parts of the class is causing a bad compile. I recreated your structure and I don't see any problem.